# Alterar nome da imagem, upload file jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate, jqgrid

Bom dia Senhores,

Alguém que já tenha trabalhado, ou que entenda o código do plugin file upload jquery [ESSE](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) Poderia me dizer como eu altero o nome da imagem antes de efetuar o upload?

Exemplo: A imagem tem o nome imagem.jpg e eu gostaria que ela pegasse alguns dados e passasse para pra imagem, pra que ela fosse salva tipo. 1_3_imagem.jpg

OBS: Estou usando o 'Basic Plus'.

Abraço!

Comment: Qual sua linguagem server-side ? PHP ?

Comment: Bom dia Diego, obrigado por responder! Estou usando php sim! Mas o upload é realizador totalmente por esse plugin!

Comment: Sim, mas para fazer o upload precisa de um `post`. E o `post` é feito pelo PHP, na pasta do plugin tem uma pasta chamada `php` e tem um arquivo lá dentro que faz o upload.

Comment: Sim Diego, o post ocorre através de uma pagina em php do próprio plugin. UploadHandler.php http://codepad.org/IbHzo4vH

Comment: O que eu preciso, é passar o valor de um <input type=hidden value'id_p'> junto com o nome da imagem. mas não estou conseguindo.